# how to build android_external_openvpn_ics with ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, external, openvpn

There is a  project  on  github  -->   https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_openvpn/tree/ics, 
after download the sourcecode, I just want to  build it  use NDK-BUILD   command  in  Linux(Centos 6.3), but the author  does not say anything about it;

So, I  just  ndk-build it  (I have test ndk-build is ok),    it shows:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.
```

What may cause this warning? And  how can I  build it, thx!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you invoke ndk-build from incorrect diretory. You must be in folder which contains jni subdirectory.

Or alternatively do what error message tells you - specify NDK_PROJECT_PATH to correct folder.

```
    NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/home/cenuser/android/sphinx/PocketSphinxDemo
 export=NDK_PROJECT_PATH
```